# update json value in oracle

Tags: json, oracle

I have a column in the table which stores data in json format.

Eg. column:

```
select jsoncol from table;
```

-- It gives

```
{"y" : "4", "n" : "0" , "default" : "4"}
```

When i try

```
select json_value(jsoncol, '$.n') from table;
```

I get the value **0**.

How can I update the value of **n** as **2**,

```
{"y" : "4", "n" : "2" , "default" : "4"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `JSON_ELEMENT_T.parse` and `<json_obj>.PUT`  method within PL/SQL.

**Setup**

```
create table tjson ( jsoncol CLOB CONSTRAINT tjson_chk CHECK (jsoncol IS JSON) );

insert into tjson (jsoncol) VALUES ( '{"y" : "4", "n" : "0" , "default" : "4"}');
```

**PL/SQL block**

```
DECLARE
    v_jsoncol       tjson.jsoncol%TYPE;
    v_json_obj      json_object_t;
    v_new_jsoncol   tjson.jsoncol%TYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT
        jsoncol
    INTO v_jsoncol
    FROM
        tjson; --use appropriate where clause

    v_json_obj := TREAT(json_element_t.parse(v_jsoncol) AS json_object_t);
    v_json_obj.put('n',2); --modifies the value
    v_new_jsoncol := v_json_obj.to_string; --converts to string

    UPDATE tjson
    SET
        jsoncol = v_new_jsoncol; --update ( use appropriate where clause)

END;
/
```

**Modified data**

```
select jsoncol FROM tjson;

JSONCOL                                                                         
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{"y":"4","n":2,"default":"4"}
```

**EDIT**:

Starting *Oracle 19c*, You may use [**`json_mergepatch`**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adjsn/updating-json-document-json-merge-patch.html#GUID-31F88F28-3D92-489B-9CCD-BD1931B91F1F)

```
select json_mergepatch (jsoncol, '{"n" : "2"}') as new_json from tjson;
NEW_JSON
{
"y" : "4",
"n" : "2",
"default" : "4"
}
```

[**Live SQL demo**](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/h6lulubnyy1fmutu5mbwrf19j)

Comment: Is there any way to do this in plain SQL (e.g. a simple UPDATE statement to remove a specific key from a JSON value) with Oracle 18c?

Comment: @a_horse : Not something that I could find. Glad to know though if there are any.

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to update JSON values via simple SQL. For example to remove from all records one of json's fields:

```
UPDATE some_table SET json_content = JSON_MERGEPATCH(json_content, '{"someKey":null}')
```

Then `someKey` should be removed from any json stored in column `json_content`. Of course instead of null there can be another value to which we want to update.