# How to update JSON string in Oracle using sql

Tags: sql, sql-update, clob

I have a table in which in one of the columns there is a json data as below

```
{"JOB_STATUS":"SUCCESS","ID":"1532","JOB_TYPE":"QUICK","JOB_DISPLAY_NAME":"Quick"}
```

I want to use sql to update `JOB_STATUS` from *SUCCESS* to *FAILURE*. How can I do it?
I saw elsewhere in stackoverflow to update json in pl/sql

[update json value in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51364996/update-json-value-in-oracle)

but how do i do it in Oracle sql. Note I can select column in the table using select but am not able to update it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know and due to my search on the web **SQL ANSI/ISO Standard** does **not** support **JSON** data type yet. However, you can use different version of SQL such as PL-SQL or T-SQL. It seems that JSON support in SQL is progressing for the ANSI/ISO SQL Standard.