# Oracle JSON api - update single record in json collection

Tags: json, oracle, api

I have CLOB field with JSON data :

```json
[
  {
    "name": "Rahul",
    "LName": "Sharma",
    "salary": "20000",
    "Age": "35"
  },
  {
    "name": "Kunal",
    "LName": "Vohra",
    "salary": "10000",
    "Age": "25"
  }
]
```

and I need update value in only one element of that array, for example in record with name: Kunal I need change salary.

I try `json_transform()` but with this I transform every field salary to new value.

```
json_transform(json_field_in_table, SET '$.salary' = 15000)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [update json value in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51364996/update-json-value-in-oracle)

Comment: It is not the same issue, i try solution from that article.

Answer (score 3):

You may use filter expression in JSON path of `json_transform` function to update specific objects:

```
with a(col) as (
  select q'$[
  {
    "name": "Rahul",
    "LName": "Sharma",
    "salary": "20000",
    "Age": "35"
  },
  {
    "name": "Kunal",
    "LName": "Vohra",
    "salary": "10000",
    "Age": "25"
  }
]$' from dual
)
select
  json_transform(
    col,
    set '$[*]?(@.name == "Kunal").salary' = '100'
  ) as res
from a
```

| RES |
| --- |
| [{"name":"Rahul","LName":"Sharma","salary":"20000","Age":"35"},{"name":"Kunal","LName":"Vohra","salary":"100","Age":"25"}] |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/b97alaF0)

Note that `"10000"` is a string in JSON, numbers should be used without quotes: `{"salary: 10000}`

Comment: Thx @astentx clear and easy way.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use json_transform because json_transform, json_exists... evaluate on the whole JSON document not on pieces of it,
even a json_exists with "'$?(@.name == "Kunal")'" will consider that the whole document matches and then update all "salary" fields.
(https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adjsn/condition-JSON_EXISTS.html#GUID-8A0043D5-95F8-4918-9126-F86FB0E203F0)

but you can:

```
select json_arrayagg(json_object (
    'name' value name, 
    'LName' value lname, 
    'salary' value case when name = 'Kunal' then 15000 else salary end, 
    'Age' value age)) as js
from 
json_table(q'~[
  {
    "name": "Rahul",
    "LName": "Sharma",
    "salary": "20000",
    "Age": "35"
  },
  {
    "name": "Kunal",
    "LName": "Vohra",
    "salary": "10000",
    "Age": "25"
  }
]~','$[*]'
columns (
    name VARCHAR2(64) path '$.name',
    LName VARCHAR2(64) path '$.LName',
    salary NUMBER path '$.salary',
    age NUMBER path '$.Age'
));
```

Comment: Thx @p3consulting for me its little bit complicated but works.